# Laravel 5.2 - Como exibir no @foreach na View, apenas registros referente ao usuário autenticado?

Tags: laravel-5

Tenho uma tabela de registos com um campo `id_user`, nessa tabela tem dados inseridos por alguns usuário do sistema. Preciso que quando o usuário se autentique no sistema, só veja os registos que ele criou. Ou seja, os registos que tem o `id_user = id` do usuário autenticado.

***Tabela Criada***

```
Schema::create('webinars', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('id_user')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('id_user')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->string('name', 255);
            $table->text('description');
            $table->dateTime('create_date');
            $table->time('time_duration');
            $table->timestamps();
});
```

***`Route`***

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function()
{

    Auth::routes();

    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
    Route::get('/webinar/gerenciarwebinar', 'GwebinarController@index');
});
```

***`Controller`***

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Webinar;

class GwebinarController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $webinars = \App\Webinar::all();
        return view('webinar.gwebinar', compact('webinars'));
    }
}
```

***`Model`***

```
namespace App;    
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Webinar extends Model
{
    //
}
```

**`View`**

```
@foreach($webinars as $webinar)   
<tr>
    <td>{{ $webinar->name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $webinar->create_date }}</td>
    <td>{{ $webinar->time_duration }}</td>
    <td><a href="" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary margin-inline">@lang('webinario.lang08')</a></td>
    <td><a href="" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary margin-inline">@lang('webinario.lang09')</a></td>
    <td>
        <div class="dropdown margin-inline">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                @lang('webinario.lang10')
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="" role="menu">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript: void(0)">
                <i class="left-menu-link-icon icmn-pencil2"><!-- --></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; @lang('webinario.lang12')</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item swal-btn-warning" href="javascript: void(0)"><i class="left-menu-link-icon icmn-bin"><!-- --></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                @lang('webinario.lang13')</a>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: você poderia colocar o seu Model?
você poderia disponibilizar o que fez até o momento?
Tem dificuldades em trabalhar com `Eloquent` ou `DB`?

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Virgilio. Segue os códigos. Minha View esta trazendo todos os registros da tabela webinars.

Comment: já fiz uma resposta!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em seu `controller` nessa **linha**:

```php
Webinar::all();
```

**troque:**

```php
Webinar::where("id_user", Auth::user()->id)->get();
```

especificando um filtro `where`, com o valor da `Auth::user()` (*`Auth::user()->id`*) que retorna o usuário logado. (não esqueça de usar o `namespace` `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;`, que já foi adicionado no exemplo de código) e mude de `all()` para `get()`

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Webinar;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class GwebinarController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $webinars = Webinar::where("id_user", Auth::user()->id)->get();
        return view('webinar.gwebinar', compact('webinars'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Erro ao executar a view: 
BadMethodCallException in C:\xampp\www\app-dlp.com\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder.php line 2450:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::all()

Comment: @BrunoOliveira peço mil desculpas quando faz `where` o método pra trazer todos muda de `all()` para `get()`, já fiz a edição, porque, é o `builder` que está acontecendo

Comment: Muito obrigado!! Funcionou perfeito. Valeu.